# first row only from multiple rows - form

Tags: php

Using the following code I am only getting the first row into the database.
Looked at many examples but I still cannot see where I am going wrong.

```
// one box for each //

<input class="bginput" name="album_name[]" size="30" type="text">

<imput type="submit" Value="submit">



<?PHP
foreach($_POST['artist_id'] as $row=>$val) {
$artist_id      = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
$album_name     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['album_name'][$row]);
$image_album_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['image_album_id'][$row]);
$track          = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['track'][$row]);
$song_name      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['song_name'][$row]);
$duration       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['duration'][$row]);


$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO songs (`image_album_id`, `member_id`, `artist_id`,      `album_name`, `track`, `song_name`, `duration`, `timestamp`)
VALUES ('$image_album_id', '".$_SESSION['member_id']."','$artist_id','$album_name', '$track', '$song_name', '$duration', UNIX_TIMESTAMP() )") or die(mysql_error());

header ('Location: song_details_add.php?success');
exit();
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are inserting only one row here ~~~

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I have closed it already, after exit(); (error in copying)

Comment: It should not be after `exit`, it must be before `header` check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have forgotten to close your foreach loop:

```
foreach($_POST['artist_id'] as $row=>$val) {
    $artist_id      = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
    $album_name     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['album_name'][$row]);
    $image_album_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['image_album_id'][$row]);
    $track          = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['track'][$row]);
    $song_name      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['song_name'][$row]);
    $duration       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['duration'][$row]);


    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO songs (`image_album_id`, `member_id`,`artist_id`,      `album_name`, `track`, `song_name`, `duration`, `timestamp`)
    VALUES ('$image_album_id', '".$_SESSION['member_id']."','$artist_id','$album_name', '$track', '$song_name', '$duration', UNIX_TIMESTAMP() )") or die(mysql_error());
} <---- missing
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks guys. Position of closing bracket stopping loop. Just could not see it. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the foreach loop, you're missing a `}`.

Comment: Wouldn't the parse error halt execution of the entire program?  Does PHP go through the loop once before realizing there's no closing bracket?

Comment: You're right, I just tested it and it halts during parsing, doesn't even start executing...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `foreach` close brace `}` is missing. But it should throw a syntax error. As you said it insert one row, I feel like you are closing the `}` after redirection.

Try this

```
<?PHP
foreach($_POST['artist_id'] as $row=>$val) {
  $artist_id      = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
  $album_name     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['album_name'][$row]);
  $image_album_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['image_album_id'][$row]);
  $track          = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['track'][$row]);
  $song_name      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['song_name'][$row]);
  $duration       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['duration'][$row]);


  $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO songs (`image_album_id`, `member_id`, `artist_id`,      `album_name`, `track`, `song_name`, `duration`, `timestamp`)
  VALUES ('$image_album_id', '".$_SESSION['member_id']."','$artist_id','$album_name', '$track', '$song_name', '$duration', UNIX_TIMESTAMP() )") or die(mysql_error());

}

header ('Location: song_details_add.php?success');
exit();
?>
```